# Memcached and Tomcat 8 Session Manager Issue

Tags: session, tomcat, memcached, tomcat8, session-management

We were using Memcached for session management in our web application with Tomcat 7 and it worked liked charm. In order for it work, I added following jars to Tomcat's lib folder

- spymemcached-2.8.12.jar
- couchbase-client-1.1.4.jar
- memcached-session-manager-tc7-1.6.5.jar
- memcached-session-manager-1.6.5.jar

And made following change to Tomcat's server.xml

```
<Context path="customersupport" docBase="customerSupportOrderCentral#v2" sessionCookieName="CUSTOMERSUPPORT-JSESSIONID">
     <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
     <Manager className="de.javakaffee.web.msm.MemcachedBackupSessionManager"
memcachedNodes="n1:oc-cs-elasticcache.w8eptf.cfg.usw1.cache.amazonaws.com:11211"
sticky="false" requestUriIgnorePattern=".*\.(ico|png|gif|jpg|css|js)$" />
</Context>
```

Now we are in process of upgrading our JDK to 1.8 and Tomcat version to 8. I have been researching online for it and it turned out since tomcat 8 doesn't support getSessionCookieName, I have to update memcache jar files for tomcat 8. so I added new set of jar files at tomcat's lib folder as below.

- spymemcached-2.11.1.jar
- memcached-session-manager-tc8-1.8.1.jar
- memcached-session-manager-1.8.1.jar
- couchbase-client-1.4.0.jar

And Kept server.xml same but now Tomcat is throwing following error while starting up.

```
06-Jan-2016 07:03:48.934 SEVERE [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement Begin event threw error
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/catalina/Lifecycle
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClassOrNull(ClassLoader.java:1012)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:413)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.ObjectCreateRule.begin(ObjectCreateRule.java:116)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1178)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:182)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.emptyElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:766)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1344)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2787)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1451)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:599)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:310)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:484)
```

If I dont change server.xml to include memcache manager, its working fine but with memcache session manager its throwing above error. I can really use some help here to resolve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried starting with a fresh tomcat 8 config (server.xml etc) adding msm config afterwards? Can you also try an early version of tomcat 8 (perhaps there were subtle incompatible changes in the last releases)?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and got stuck for 2 days. The issue on my end was I had the below memcache specific jars in tomcat/lib and in another project specific classpath - tomcat/{project}/conf. The issue got resolved  when I removed these jars from tomcat/{project}/conf

spymemcached-2.11.1.jar
memcached-session-manager-tc8-1.8.1.jar
memcached-session-manager-1.8.1.jar